# char array to unsigned char python

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to translate this c code into python, but Im having problems with the `char*` to `ushort*` conversion:

```
void sendAsciiCommand(string command) {
    unsigned int nchars = command.length() + 1; // Char count of command string
    unsigned int nshorts = ceil(nchars / 2);    // Number of shorts to store the string
    std::vector<unsigned short> regs(nshorts);  // Vector of short registers

    // Transform char array to short array with endianness conversion
    unsigned short *ascii_short_ptr = (unsigned short *)(command.c_str());

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nshorts; i++)
         regs[i] = htons(ascii_short_ptr[i]);          

    return std::string((char *)regs.data());
}
```

As long I have tried with this code in Python 2.7:

```
from math import ceil
from array import array


command = "hello"
nchars = len(command) + 1
nshorts = ceil(nchars/2)
regs = array("H", command)
```

But it gives me the error:

> ValueError: string length not a multiple of item size

Any help?

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is not a question. What have you tried, what doesn't work? [ask] [mcve]

Comment: I have edited a bit the answer, thank you for the advise

Comment: read the array documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception text:

```
ValueError: string length not a multiple of item size
```

means what is says, i.e., the length of the string from which you are trying to create an array must be a multiple of the item size. In this case the item size is that of an `unsigned short`, which is 2 bytes. Therefore the length of the string must be a multiple of 2. `hello` has length 5 which is not a multiple of 2, so you can't create an array of 2 byte integers from it. It will work if the string is 6 bytes long, e.g. `hello!`.

```
>>> array("H", 'hello!')
array('H', [25960, 27756, 8559])
```

You might still need to convert to network byte order. `array` uses the native byte order on your machine, so if your native byte order is little endian you will need to convert it to big endian (network byte order). Use `sys.byteorder` to check and `array.byteswap()` to swap the byte order if required:

```
import sys
from array import array

s = 'hello!'
regs = array('H', s)
print(regs)
# array('H', [25960, 27756, 8559])
if sys.byteorder != 'big':
    regs.byteswap()
print(regs)
# array('H', [26725, 27756, 28449])
```

---

However, it's easier to use [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) to convert straight to network byte order if necessary:

```
import struct

s = 'hello!'
n = len(s)/struct.calcsize('H')
regs = struct.unpack('!{}H'.format(n), s)
print(regs)
#(26725, 27756, 28449)
```

If you really need an `array`:

```
regs = array('H', struct.unpack('!{}H'.format(n), s))
```

---

It's also worth pointing out that your C++ code contains an error. If the string length is odd an extra byte will be read at the end of the string and this will be included in the converted data. That extra byte will be `\0` as the C string should be null terminated, but the last `unsigned short` should either be ignored, or you should check that the length of the string is multiple of an `unsigned short`, just as Python does.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly.

I supposed that the problem was the data size, from 8 to 16 bits if the string is uneven, do u know how C deal with this problem on the conversion??

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I just saw your last paragraph, thank you very much for the info!